# What game is this character creation screen from?

Tags: game-identification

Does anyone recognize this game?

[image]

I saw this image and it looks rather cool. I was thinking divinity but don't remember this class.

Comment: I searched for this image on Google Images and got a lot of exact matching image results all showing that this game is *Baldur's Gate 3*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar images seen [here](https://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/baldurs-gate-3-character-creation-guide/) suggest it's Baldur's Gate 3.

Backing Video:

Comment: Don't know why you got the downvote, but a better reference may be https://baldursgate3.game/, where under Screenshots you can see a screenshot of the Character Creation screen.

Comment: No idea either. He is 100% correct :). Bought the game :D. Then regret buying it because I actually think it's a cool game... but not fully released. Should've waited a bit :).